# IS document.getElementById('app') Always the 2nd argument for ReactDOM.render()?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Please bare with me as I am new, but I haven't found a clear answer anywhere.

I just want to know if anything else can be passed as the 2nd argument for ReactDOM.render(), all of my lessons/tutorials has:  document.getElementById('app') ..

I'm just curious as to what else can pass through if any... Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Yes and no. You must pass in a DOM element. You do not have to get that DOM element by using getElementById('app'). It could use a different selector or have a different ID. If that is what you are asking

Comment: Ok, what you said just made sense... I was just curious because all of the lessons are showing me one thing.  WOuld you happen to have any examples? (just for a better visual). Thanks!

Comment: Well it all comes down to what element you have in your HTML that you want to put your app in. If it's `<div id="react" />` you'd want to use `document.getElementById('react')`. There's nothing special about `app`, it just has to match your HTML

Comment: oh ok... got it...